# The volume bounded by a sphere and a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

If I want to find the volume bounded below by the sphere
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9$$ and above by the plane z=1 .

Can we solve it as following?

$$V=\int\int_R\int_{z=-\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}^{z=1}dzdA$$
$$V=\int\int_R (1+\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2})dA$$
where R is the projection in xy plane of the intersection of the sphere and the plane z=1.
$$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=2\sqrt{2}}(1+\sqrt{9-r^2})rdrd\theta$$
If not , why ?

Note: 
I have a second solution :

Get the volume bounded below by the plane z=1 and above by the sphere , then subtract this volume from the volume of the sphere.

If you have any other solutions , I will be grateful if you provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your answer only includes the portion of the volume that lies within the cylinder $x^2+y^2=8$ so you need an extra piece if your volume is what I think it is from the description. I get
$$\begin{align}V &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\sqrt2}\int_{-\sqrt{9-r^2}}^1dz\ rdrd\theta+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{2\sqrt2}^3\int_{-\sqrt{9-r^2}}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}}dz\ rdrd\theta \\
& =2\pi\int_0^{2\sqrt2}\left(1+\sqrt{9-r^2}\right)rdr+2\pi\int_0^{2\sqrt2}2\sqrt{9-r^2}rdr \\
& =2\pi\left[\frac12r^2-\frac13\left(9-r^2\right)\right]_0^{2\sqrt2}+2\pi\left[-\frac23\left(9-r^2\right)\right]_{2\sqrt2}^3 \\
& =\frac{80\pi}3\end{align}$$
As can be confirmed by fixing up the limits in @José Carlos Santos middle integral.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand. $R$ is the projection of *what*?

I would comput it in cylindrical coordinates:$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3\int_0^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Comment: Where did the $\rho$ come from? Why not $z,r,\theta$?

Comment: @KSplitX It's just the notation that I am used to. Use $r$ instead of $\rho$, if you wish.

Comment: I mean the projection of the intersection of the sphere with the plane z=1.

Comment: @MCS That intersection is a circle. But which projection are you talking about?

Comment: Can you write your integral as a triple one @MCS

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought the projection is the circle of the intersection .. but  I think now I was wrong because the projection will be a circle with radius 3 ( the intersection of sphere with z=0) and the circle of intersection of sphere with z=1 .. so in my first method , we will have 2 projections , so we can not complete the integration .. so the first method is wrong ?

Comment: @MCS I am not interely sure about the meaning of what you wrote but, yes. I suppose that it is wrong.